# how to use number_format on yii2, Im a newbie,

Tags: function, yii2-advanced-app

on index.php

```
` <?= GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'filterModel' => $searchModel,         'columns' => [             ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],             'kode',
        'uraian',
        'spek:ntext',
        'satuan',
        'harga',`
```

I need to use number_format on 'harga',
thanks

I m a beginner and dont know much about the routes on yii 2

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a callable to format the value of the column.

```
'spek:ntext',
'satuan',
[
    'attribute' => 'harga',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return number_format($model->harga);
    }
],
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used like this :

```
[
            'attribute' => 'grand_total',
            'enableSorting' => false,
            'value' => function ($model) {
                 return number_format($model->grand_total,2);
            },
        ],
```